# CSS3 Panorama Viewer Get Spherical Coordinate

Tags: css, graphics, viewer, coordinate, panoramas

I have a 3D CSS3 panorama viewer coming from cubemap.
No WebGL is used

http://ec2-72-44-32-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com/cubepanorama/

I have navigation working in the panorama..
basically it is rotated by Y axis for the turn and X axis for the Tilt.

What i want to do is simple, click on a point in this example, then center that point in the panorama viewer. Thats All!
the click doesnt really work well right now.

To make it better, I need to translate the mouse click coordinate into the actual 3D coordinate of a point on the cube.
Anybody can help me please?

Thanks